# Page loads within a page, rather can completely reloading

Tags: html, href, wiki

I wrote some custom HTML code in my Wikidot article - instead of the "original" Wikidot syntax, I have to use `<a href="/page">` for links.

The content of my custom HTML block is like this:

```
<section class="intro">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Headline-line text</h1>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="timeline">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div>
        <time>Time value </time> Text. <a href="/site">Link here.</a>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

The problem is that it loads the entire content of the HTML into that carefully selected small portion of the original site.

[image]

I can only assume that it has something to do with `<div>`s, as I've already seen this issue on other sites. Hence my assumption is that there must be a general source of this issue, and this is why I'm asking.

What's the reason of this problem and how can I avoid it?

Comment: you might need to add a `target` to the anchor - why not use the wiki syntax for links tho'?

Comment: @ochi I needed some custom code for functionality Wikidot can't provide on its own - a vertical timeline. I got an example from somewhere and added it as a custom HTML block (it translate CSS & JS too) but within said blocks, Wikidot syntax is practically non-existent.

Comment: does an iframe suite your needs? http://snippets.wikidot.com/code:include-any-page

Comment: also, can you confirm that the only the custom HTML block is returned when you click on the link (as opposed to the entire page with header and sidenav)?

Comment: @ochi iframe doesn't seem to work. About confirming: how can I do that? (targeting works fine but makes things a bit over-complicated without the wikidot syntax translation)

Comment: I am afraid there is not enough information on your question (which is on the edge of being off-topic) to be able to provide you with an answer.  As for checking, you can use Chrome's developer tools (or Firefox) and watch the network's activity

Comment: @ochi essentially, adding `target` did what was my main issue. Though a new issue resurfaced, the question is answered, so there's no need to close this one. Thanks for your help!

Comment: For the benefit of others, add a complete answer and mark it as such... Other issues can be asked as a separate question